# branch new feature

Tags: git

I'm working on a project and created a new branch for a new feature. if I do many things wrong .. How could return to the main branch without bringing the changes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming you mean that you made a `work` branch from `master` and made all your checkins there, all you have to do is `git checkout master` to go back.

Comment: Sounds like you have uncommitted changes.  Either commit them or throw them out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really done with the branch and are ready to abandon it and DELETE IT LOSING ALL THE CHANGES you made, you can delete the branch with:

```
git branch -d mybranch
```

Note that you will LOSE ALL CHANGES made on the branch!

Comment: if i deleted the branch no deleted changes in the working directory. for this i commit in the branch mybranch and deleted branch. why commit??